# Will this code correctly determine if two types are equal?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, types

I'm a little foggy on `System.Type` versus an actual class type (like `Object` or `XmlDocument`) in .NET... will this code correctly determine if the type of a particular object is equal to a class I specify?

```vb
' Given "myObject" (unknown type), and some class type (let's say "MyClass")...

If myObject.GetType.Equals(MyClass)

If TypeOf(myObject) Is MyClass

If myObject.GetType() Is MyClass
```

Which one is correct?

Bonus points if you can provide some information on what a class identifier is versus what a `System.Type` is. :)

*Note: The language doesn't matter here, VB.NET or C# is fine, the code above is pseudocode.*

Comment: I always thought an object was technically a Type and all classes were inherited from an object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fist let's take a look on the three options you gave:

```vb
If myObject.GetType.Equals(MyClass)
```

This will probably result in a error, since the equals expects a `System.Type`, not a class. A class definition is not a `System.Type`, but you can retrieve it using the `typeof` operator. So you could do `instance.Equals(typeof(MyClass))`, which would return true if the object is of the given class.

```vb
If TypeOf(myObject) Is MyClass
```

Conversely, you can't use `typeof` with instances, only with classes, so the above code would fail. Also, the `is` operator automatically checks the typing so you can't do a `typeof` or a `GetType` when using it. You should go with `if myObject is MyClass`, which would return true if myObject **can be cast to `MyClass`**. This is different from saying that it's an instance of that type, because it could be that myObject is an instance of a class that inherits from `MyClass`.

```vb
If myObject.GetType() Is MyClass
```

Again, the `is` operator already checks the type on both operands, so you should go with `if myObject is MyClass`.

---

All that said, I'd like to explain the "theory" behind the type system. I'm no specialist, so I'm giving you a more practical explanation:

- A class definition label (like `MyClass`) is not a System.Type. A `System.Type` is a metadata class that is generated by the CLR to represent the type defined by your label. To retrieve the `System.Type` related to a certain class definition label, use the `typeof` operator as follows:

  ```cs
  System.Type MyClassType = typeof(MyClass);
  ```
- On a object instance, you can retrieve the `System.Type` metadata by calling the method `GetType()` on it. It will give you an instance of `System.Type` related to the class that represents the actual instance. This means that if your object is being treated by the compiler as a interface or a base class, `.GetType()` still gives you the **most derived type for that instance.**
- You can compare `System.Type` in order to check if two objects are instances of the same class, but again, beware that your instance can be of a more derived type; The equality will fail (the `System.Type`of a more derived class is different than that of a less derived one).
- If you need to take inheritance into account, you can use the method [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx), like this:

  ```cs
  BaseClass instance = new DerivedClass();

  System.Type type = instance.GetType();

  if ((typeof(BaseClass)).IsAssignableFrom(type))    // returns true
  {
  }
  ```
- C# and VB.Net gives you two operators that enables you to do type checking on the fly, `is` and `as`. `is` does automatic typing retrieval and is preferred over getting the `System.Type` yourself. It accounts for inheritance as well:

  ```cs
  DerivedClass instance = new DerivedClass();

  System.Type type = instance.GetType();

  if (instance is BaseClass)    // returns true
  {
  }
  ```
- If you need to check the type **and** cast the object use `as`:

  ```cs
  DerivedClassinstance = new DerivedClass();

  System.Type type = instance.GetType();

  AnotherClass another = instance as AnotherClass;

  if (another == null)    // returns true
  {
      // Do proper error treatment... throw an exception or something
  }
  ```

  What you **cannot** do with `as` is not perform proper result checking; The problem is that if you don't check it for null and use it, you get an `NullReferenceException`, which will hide the correct problem (the cast failed). If you are sure you can do the cast, then use a explicit cast:

  ```cs
  DerivedClassinstance = new DerivedClass();

  System.Type type = instance.GetType();

  AnotherClass another = (AnotherClass)instance; // throws
  ```

  This will throw an `InvalidCastException`, so the code will be easier to debug.

Comment: Although this question is tagged both C# and VB, the syntax in the OP is clearly VB.  This is one of the areas where the keywords are similar, but do different things.  You suggestion for the first `Equals(typeof(MyClass))` will not compile and the similar assertion about `typeof` for classes instead of instances is backwards for VB.  Also, the `Is` operator in VB is different than C#.  In VB `Is` performs reference comparisons, not type-checks.

Comment: @Gideon: the OP clearly stated that 'The language doesn't matter here, VB.NET or C# is fine, the code above is pseudocode.', so I went with C# that I'm more familiar with.

Answer (score 15):

The `.GetType()` approach could fail if the item is null, so you might want a null check first.

I don't know about VB, but in C# you use `is` with the *object*, not it's type - i.e.

```
if(obj is MyClass) {...}
```

Another difference between `is` (done correctly) and `GetType()`/`Equals` - the difference here is subclasses. If the item is actually an `SuperMyClass` (inherited from `MyClass`) then `Equals` or `==` will return `false` - however, `is` will return true.

`typeof` is restricted to use with *types*, not *variables* - i.e. `typeof(MyClass)`, but not `typeof(obj)`. If you want the actual type of an object in a variable, use `obj.GetType()`.

Personally, I would use (in C#):

```
var typed = obj as MyClass;
if(typed != null) {
    // do something interesting with typed
}
```

as this does a type-check and cast once rather than twice

Comment: What if I have to use System.Type, like if a class contains a property of type `Type` - how can I check if that `Type` is a particular class? I can't use `Is` with VB, it spits out an error.

Comment: For the record, `TypeOf` in VB works with variables and not types.  Since this question was also tagged VB, the equivalent syntax (w/o newlines) is `Dim typed = TryCast(obj, MyClass)  If typed IsNot Nothing Then ...`

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, `is` will make true for class and subclass.For example:

```
class B:Program{}
class Program{}
Program a = new Program();
B b = new B();
if (b is Program) ; // true
if (a is Program) ; // true
if (a is B) ; // false
if (b is B) ; //false
```

and use Equals and typeof([ClassName]) is just equal to class, not to subclass:

```
class B:Program{}
class Program{}
Program a = new Program();
B b = new B();
if (b.GetType() == typeof(program)) ; // false
if (b.GetType() == typeof(B)) ; // true
if (a.GetType() == typeof(B)) ; // false
if (a.GetType() == typeof(Program)) ; //true
```

Comment: Where does program come from? It isn't a declared type in your code so will result in a syntax error. Did you mean `if (b.GetType() == typeof(Program)) ;` by any chance?